# Is there a way to deactivateApp for infinite duration using UIAutomation in iOS?

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I am testing an iOS application and I want to keep my app in background until I will not wake it up.

I have read [deactivateAppForDuration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIATargetClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIATarget/deactivateAppForDuration).It is saying that you can deactivate your app means you can send your app in background for particular amount of time.

I thought if I give "-1" value to deactivateAppForDuration , it will send app in background for infinite time but I was wrong , it will wake up app in vary less time.

So is there a way to keep app in background for infinite time using UIAutomation.

Comment: did you try simply adding a very very large value? :)

Comment: @Vish I have considered that solution but I want to know that is there any proper way so that app will not come in foreground until user want.
Anyway thanks

Comment: If I remember correctly deactivating is a blocking function right? So there's no way to execute code until it returns. So outside of a large value I'm not sure there's a solution.

Comment: Yes @Braains you are right , deactivateApp is blocking function , so large value for time will also not work

Comment: So you're trying to deactivate the app and then continue executing code inside of Instruments?

Comment: @Braains yes exactly

Comment: The only way that I can see this happening is if you use the delay statement in Instruments and coordinate that with an external script that somehow triggers the home button on the iPad. But I don't know how you would achieve that.

Comment: You can test if this will work by just pressing the home button on the device during a test execution and see if Instruments will still run. Obviously commands to press buttons or interact with the UI will fail though.

Comment: Or, to summarize: instruments UI Automation still has a lot of holes that can't be filled :( Maybe iOS 9 will have some improvements.